Why does unwrapping my cylindrical pushpin look weird?
Hey all I have what I believe is a fairly basic question but can't for the life of me figure out what I'm doing wrong.  I'm creating a 3D model of a pushpin, extruded from a cylinder.

I have it cleanly modeled (no overlapping vertices) and marked plenty of seams, but any time I do an Unwrap, I end up with spaghetti garbage:

My first thought was it's some issue with the cylinder cap at the top and bottom being an n-gon.  One thing I read said they should have an odd number of faces, but both even and odd give the same results. Like I said, I feel like this must be something simple, but for the life of me I can't figure it out.
Edit: One other thing I'm struggling to figure out is what the Unwrap function takes into account.  For example, I can get a decent unwrap using Smart UV Project or Cylindrical Projection, but if I click Unwrap again, it just slightly modifies the existing map, rather than unwrapping from scratch using my seams etc.  Is that the expected behavior?  If I want a clean unwrap, do I need to Reset between each unwrap?
Edit 2: Here's the link for the Blender Exchange:


From your image, you don't appear to have marked a seam round the lower circumference of the inner cylinder where it splays out. It might be an idea to share your Blend file which you can do via via https://blend-exchange.com/ following the instructions there to copy the full link on that page. Then edit your question here and paste the link into it.

Hey thanks for the tip!  I have tried marking seams at various circumferences and it hasn't seemed to make much of a difference, but I uploaded the file in case anyone wants to take a look at it.

The image of your UV unwrap is indicating that some vertices of the UV's have been pinned. These pinned vertices are the ones coloured red. Pinned vertices means that they will not be influenced by any later UV marking of seams and re-unwrapping. What you need to do is unpin these vertices. To do that, in the UV editor select everything then use the shortcut keys Alt + P. After doing that there will be no more red vertices and when you UV unwrap again it should unwrap as expected, unwrapping as many separate UV islands. Btw, its the P key that pins the selected vertices.

Hello and welcome. Please use a title that matches the content of the post. It should read like a question, be descriptive but succinct, unique and identifying, summarizing the problem so that anyone searching for similar issues is likely to find this. Remove anything superfluous, avoid using words like "this", "help with", "issue" or "question about", instead describe what "it" is. Remember, your title is the first thing visitors see, answers you get depend heavily on it. See What is the problem of asking “How do I do this?"

Just to add that I think you have added to many UV seams for such a simple object. I would suggest you experiment a little, for example try removing some of the edge ring UV seams around the top part of the model then do another unwrap to see how that changes things. And because you do have UV seams on the model don't bother trying to unwrap using the Smart UV Project or Cylinder Projection methods just use the very basic Unwrap option, that's the first option in the list when open the UV drop-down menu.

@3fingeredfrog Bruh I don't want to tell you how much time I wasted messing around with marking seams, adding edges, deleting faces... You're right, I somehow pinned the vertices, which was also causing the issue of Unwrapping with different settings not changing anything.  You saved my life!

Saving a life, I will put that down as my good deed for the day lol .

As @3fingeredfrog says, you need to unpin those vertices in the UV editor by selecting All, hitting P and then checking Clear in the bottom-left Operator menu. I've then replaced all the double seams that you had added with single ones as shown below.

Then a simple U > Unwrap gives the result below.


After Unpinning the pinned vertices try removing some more of the edge loop seams. This will result fewer UV islands and a cleaner UV unwrap especially if you do a little UV editing.

